# Objective-c ViewControllers and Views

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller

I know this has been talked about ad nauseam on here but I'd like to get some perspective from other developers:

If I have a view controller with a view and then I add subviews to that view, does each subview need its' own viewcontroller or can the first viewcontroller also control the subviews?

So

```
UIViewController
  UIView
    UIView
     UIButton
     UILabel
    UIView
     ...
```

the subviews do not take up the whole screen - they are for the most part the width of the screen but maybe 200.0f tall or less. They display information for a sales tool app.

The rule of thumb I was presented when I first started iOS development was if the view took up the whole screen, then it required its own viewcontroller, if not make it the subview of a viewcontrollers.view

Just wondering what the accepted approach is.

Answer (score 0):

The View controller can access the views that are created in XIB, just create IBOutlet properties for the views in view controller source files and link the views to file's owner in interface builder.

Your rule of thumb is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use IB that much, mostly hard code it but I started a new job and was looking over some of their existing apps created by my predecessor and he most of had 40-50 viewcontrollers in one app. That didn't seem right to me.

Comment: It's quite normal to have 40-50 view controllers for a production app, you can divide your code so that your custom view handles the drawing etc and view controller handles the events.